Anime guy is forced to eat snow, eats snow, complains about it (80s or early 90s)
I watched this show between 1998 and 2003. As far as I recall, the footage quality (mostly color saturation) suggests 80s or early 90s. Unfortunately, I can recall only a single scene, but I feel it is specific enough to make identification possible.
Scene 1
Scene setting: exterior, flat plain covered in snow
Smug Villain accosts Generic Blonde Male Hero with Spiky Hair. They fight. After a brief round of fisticuffs, Smug Villain uses psychic-powers/martial-arts/bloodbending to take control of Blondie's body and forces him to rapidly eat snow.
Blondie proceeds to eat snow, rapidly shoving handfuls into his mouth, alternating between left and right hand, and has interior monologue about how horrible it is that he's eating snow and that he will die.
Cut!
